# open source svn client java library which can be used in commercial development

Tags: java, svn

Is their any SVN client Java library which i can use in a commercial development.

Comment: Are you looking to use code from an SVN library developed in Java for your own commercial use? Please clarify your intent.

Comment: i want to connect to a svn repo using using java library

Answer (score 10):

The subversion project itself provides [java bindings](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/subversion/bindings/javahl/) under the [apache license](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/LICENSE) like the rest of subversion. The apache license allows inclusion of the code in closed source projects, as long as you give proper attribution.

The [SvnClientAdapter code in subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnClientAdapter.html) can wrap these java bindings to provide a friendlier higher-level API, under the same license.

Answer (score 4):

SVNKit (http://svnkit.com) has both open-source licensing (similar to the GPL) as well as a commercial licensing option.