# SVN java library

Tags: java, svn, tortoisesvn, svnkit, javahl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [open source svn client java library which can be used in commercial development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512300/open-source-svn-client-java-library-which-can-be-used-in-commercial-development)

I want to access SVN from a java program. I want a open source java library for SVN , except SVNkit.  Since SVNKit is licenced I cannot use it. I need a open source one.

Comment: SVNKit is dual licensed. It is free for open source projects.

Comment: @Atilla  : but i need it for commercial project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SVNKit is open source and as far as i know is the only pure Java implementation out there, if you looking for an alternative, take a look at :

- [JavaHL](http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL)
- [SvnClientAdapter](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnClientAdapter.html)

Each of them are not pure Java implementation but rely on an underling C library accessing it through JNI .

Comment: Note: SVNKit is GPL dual licensed open source. So you need a commercial license, if you want to use it inside a commercial application!