# how to Checkin a file generated from Java program to SVN

Tags: java, api, svn, automation

Here is background : i'm creating a code generator in java as an api. This creates some macro files. I want to know if there are any tools/API's avialbale from SVN that i can call to place these generated Macro files under a directory in SVN. 
basically connect to SVN from a java program. check in the generated file.

Comment: [open source svn client java library which can be used in commercial development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512300/open-source-svn-client-java-library-which-can-be-used-in-commercial-development)

Comment: I guess that first comment tells you what need to know, but besides that: please read the help center to understand what SO is for. Such questions as yours (about some tool library to do xyz) ... do not fit here.

Answer (score 0):

There are several libs for accessing svn repositories from java e.g. SVNKit.  With such a lib you can perform everything what you know from your svn gui.